Problems working with xarray .where() function and dask (Python)
TL;DR: I can't use the 'where()' function and the 'max()' function from xarray together in a dataset chunked by dask.
Hello, so I'm new working with dask and I'm having a problem that I can't just figure out what to do.
I have this script that opens a .h5 file (580GB size) with a bunch of variables in which some are 4D (time=217,z=120,y=400,x=400). I'm working via SSH inside a cluster and can connect to specific nodes of it by just typing 'ssh ib-node1' in terminal if I want to use the node1 for example, and I'm defining the chunks manually by calculating the division of the time coordinate (the coordinate that I'm interested of doing operations) by the number of nodes available (normally it's 3).
So, I'm trying to find the maximum, minimum or mean of a specific variable, like the maximum of 'w' for each time in the example below, and that works fine. But I need to add a condition based on another variable to separate the part of the data that I want, so I use the 'where()' function, and there's my main issue. When I add the 'where()' function with another variable that is the exact same size of 'w' in the example (let's call it 'cm3') and then compute it, it returns this giant error message below the script.
My guess is that maybe it has something to do with the 'nanmax()' function built in xarray, and since I'm using the 'where()' function it returns 'nan's where the condition is false. I tried to use 'fillna(0)' to solve this, but it just returns another big error message. Can anyone help me to solve this?
This is the script I've tried to run to find the maximum of 'w' where 'cm3' is bigger than 0.01:
import xarray as xr
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client, SSHCluster

nodes = ['ib-node2','ib-node3','ib-node4'] #I want to use the nodes 2,3 and 4
cluster = SSHCluster(nodes) #I tell to the cluster which hosts I want to use (don't know if it's correct)
client = Client(cluster) #Define the client

ds = xr.open_dataset('myfile.h5', chunks = {'time': round(217/3)}) #Opening the file with chunks

w_max = ds['w'].max(dim=['z','y','x']).compute() #This line works fine

w_max_where = ds['w'].where(ds['cm3']>0.01).max(dim=['z','y','x']).compute() #This line returns the big error message below


This is the big error message (I had to cut part of it to post it here so I put the '[...]':
2024-05-02 15:41:20,676 - distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to Serialize
[...]
TypeError: 0-dim memory has no length
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/gbalestra/softwares/anaconda/envs/teste/lib/python3.12/site-packages/xarray/core/dataarray.py", line 1102, in compute
    return new.load(**kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gbalestra/softwares/anaconda/envs/teste/lib/python3.12/site-packages/xarray/core/dataarray.py", line 1076, in load
    ds = self._to_temp_dataset().load(**kwargs)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gbalestra/softwares/anaconda/envs/teste/lib/python3.12/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py", line 792, in load
    evaluated_data = chunkmanager.compute(*lazy_data.values(), **kwargs)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gbalestra/softwares/anaconda/envs/teste/lib/python3.12/site-packages/xarray/core/daskmanager.py", line 70, in compute
    return compute(*data, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gbalestra/softwares/anaconda/envs/teste/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 628, in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gbalestra/softwares/anaconda/envs/teste/lib/python3.12/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 2245, in _gather
    raise exc
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError: ('_nanmax_skip-aggregate-7e0dcde6316f7714e66ca30a17555f35', 0)


Hi, did you tried without Dask on a subset of your data to see if the problem is related to Dask or not? Also, the way you are using dask-ssh will start one Scheduler and two workers, and your chunking on only three chunks might not be optimal for streaming computation.

Hi, thank you for the comment. I'd tried to work on my data by subsets with time loops so my code could work each time alone. It took a lot of processing time and I'm not able to use the vectorized operation because it deals with +30GB arrays. Part of the problem was in the installation of the packages dask and asyncssh, and now I can run the command in question, but I have to deal with one additional condition in the where function and when I put the two together this error appears again (maybe because it's 3 really big objects?). I think it has something to do with the workers/scheduler.


About the scheduler and workers, I have no idea what I'm doing. Can you give me a hint? I have 3 nodes with 40 cores each and I'm aiming to use them all. I don't really know how to use properly the SSHCluster in this scenario, or how to chunk properly. I guess it could be the main issue dealing with these big objects. Do I have to deploy in each node manually a scheduler and 40 workers? And then just run my code to do the operations?

